# GPU crash in long running THREE.js application with clean JavaScript Heap profile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

Our long running THREE.js application (24/7) is crashing after a few days of use. I've put together stress tests that simulate user interaction, which are in a `while(true)` loop and these appear to take anywhere from 3 - 4 days to crash with a `WebGL_Context_Lost` event, which typically indicates a GPU process crash.

I am well versed in Chrome Dev Tools Heap profiler and have run numerous tests which all came back with no objects left between each simulation (same simulations described above).

Here's one of the screenshots showing only system objects left behind (ignore the size of the first Snapshot):
[image]

Both JavaScript memory and GPU memory climb in Chrome task manager, but stabilize (I feel GC is being deferred because of how frequent these operations are). There isn't a continuous climb towards a crash, indicative of a leak.

Versions: Chrome 65-66, Windows 10, THREE.js r91

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible for JavaScript heap to be leak-free, yet something to leak in the GPU?
2. What tools can I use to look for GPU memory leaks?
3. Is it possible to know what exactly caused a WebGL_context_lost? (Chrome logs?)
4. Has anyone dealt with this before?
5. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE:**

The simulation was run for 30 minute intervals, with me capturing a heap snapshot followed by a screenshot of Chrome task manager (AFAIK Capturing Heap Snapshots also runs GC).

**5:00 - Initial Snapshot from Home Screen**

[image]

**5:30**

[image]

**6:00**

[image]

**6:30**

[image]

**7ish**

[image]

**8PM**

[image]

**Here's the confusing part: even after performing a manual GC, GPU memory stayed at ~490MB, until, I switched tabs and then it was back down to initial**

[image]

If switching the tabs cleared the GPU memory back to initial, maybe the issue is that Chrome is trying to be too smart and not disposing of GPU objects, which puts a pressure on the machine and eventually runs out of memory?

Note: these tests are run on an Intel i5 with an Intel Iris Graphics 540 on the latest drivers (23.20.16.4973 - 2018-02-28)

We have also seen this on the Iris 640 running the latest drivers.

For those interested, here's a comparison of heap snapshots at 7:30 and 5:30:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2 - looking like a driver issue**

After reloading the page, 2 minutes into the simulation, GPU crashed with "Rats, WebGL hit a Snag". Memory hasn't had a chance to come up, so I doubt there is a leak.

Windows System logs have warnings that the graphics driver stopped working, which happen at the same exact time.

[image: GPU crash and corresponding Windows logs]

Timestamp of WebGL Context lost error in Chrome: `10:07:52.938PM`

Timestamp of Windows System log driver issue (I am guessing it is rounded up): `10:07:53PM`

**1. Is it safe to say this is a driver issue?**

**2. Did Chrome kill the GPU process and in the process log to Windows Logs OR did the driver misbehave which in return caused Chrome to kill the GPU process?**

This machine is running the latest driver via Windows Update, I am going to uninstall and update using Intel's driver and re-run tests.

Comment: There could be a driver bug, but otherwise I would doubt the GPU leak theory. Since you aren't seeing an overall climb in memory usage on either side, it's also unlikely that GC isn't doing its part, or that you're sending too many new buffers to the GPU. What about the overall browser memory? If the whole browser crashes, it may recover, but it would have lost the WebGL context in the process.

Comment: @TheJim01, that's interesting. I didn't think of a case where Chrome would recover the tab but not the context. Would that result in a page reload? (in which case I can easily instrument it). Please see my update as to why I think something wonky is happening to the GPU/Chrome, thank you!

Comment: Based on your Update 2, it sounds like you've almost narrowed it down. It also sounds like you're using an integrated GPU. Is there any chance of trying your application on a system with a discrete GPU? Also, does your system use switchable graphics? If so, your system could be switching GPUs, which would result in a loss of context yet possibly maintain your application state.

Comment: @TheJim01 This is running on an integrated GPU. I wasn't able to reproduce this on my Macbook Pro with discrete graphics, although this could be due to OSX vs. Windows (mainly because of ANGLE). I am curious though, we had no such issues until mid March. AFAIK, no driver updates were performed (drivers were dated to December). The only thing that changed is Chrome was auto-updated to 65. I'd like to rule out Chrome, so I am re-running the test using Electron.js (only reliable way to downgrade Chrome :() - it uses Chrome 59 atm.

Comment: Interesting that you mention ANGLE. I suppose it could be an issue at that layer. ANGLE is maintained as part of the Chromium project. I don't know how quickly Chrome integrates Chromium changes, but you could potentially grab a pre-March copy of Chromium (maybe from January or before?) and see if the issue still exists. You can also pull the latest version of Chromium to see if the issue is resolved (and then just wait for Chrome to catch up).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue: 
A three.js based application that loads some data from the server every few seconds and displays it with animation. I should run for days.

I made sure I dispose every mesh and material I don't use and yet - the GPU process memory kept growing till the application crashes.

The solution I came with was to have an HTML container page with two `iframe` elements, one on top of the other. The main application then loads to the top iframe, then every N minutes the same application is loaded to the other `iframe` and they switch (toggle visibility)

The previous `iframe.src` is set to `""`.
I keeps the GPU memory clean, and since the main application is stateless - nothing is actually noticeable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is a nice hack, really need to remember this